# Use Jquery to append html with css?

Tags: jquery, css, styling

I want to create a html link with some styling in it.

right now I'm using:

```
$('<a/>').text('sample')
         .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/').appendTo('body');

$('a').css({
               float: 'right',
               fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
               position: 'static',
               display: 'inline',
               visibility: 'inherit'
          });
```

but instead create and refer the  tag 2 times, is there are simpler way to do it? like:

```
$('<a/>').text('sample')
         .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/').appendTo('body');
         .css({
               float: 'right',
               fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
               position: 'static',
               display: 'inline',
               visibility: 'inherit'
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have semicolon at wrong place that terminates method chaining.

```
 .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/').appendTo('body');
                                                        ^^^
```

You code would be

```
$('<a/>').text('sample')
     .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/').appendTo('body')
     .css({
           float: 'right',
           fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
           position: 'static',
           display: 'inline',
           visibility: 'inherit'
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('<a/>').text('sample')
     .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/').appendTo('body')
     .css({
           float: 'right',
           fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
           position: 'static',
           display: 'inline',
           visibility: 'inherit'
      });
```

you are terminating method chaining after giving "appendTo" so "css" will not be applicable there....try to remove that semicolon ';' at the end of appendTo('body') to include "css" also

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<a>').text('sample')
         .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
         .css({
               float: 'right',
               fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
               position: 'static',
               display: 'inline',
               visibility: 'inherit'
          }).appendTo('body');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wQLmw/